# Wordpress and cut URL while uploading

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I m working with `wordpress` + `acf` + `rest acf` and I'm needing to cut some URL.

Instead of having a full URL of image displayed in my **JSON :**

```
"intro_img": {
            "url": "http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/app\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/intro.png",
        }
```

I need something much more **like :**

```
"intro_img": {
                "url": "uploads/2016/10/intro.png",
            }
```

What can I do to cut that `URL` of only for files uploaded ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: replace get_site_url()."/wp-content" with ''

Comment: Why not just explode your path at wp-content/uploads and cut it before processing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```
$data = array('intro_img'=>array('url'=>"http:/127.0.0.1/app/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/intro.png"));
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems great, but the fact is that I don't know where to put that code, in which file